# error: invalid input syntax for integer: when passing strings

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I have the following function in node.js that makes a query to postgres based based on `name_url`. Sometimes it works and sometimes it just doesn't work.

Also I'm using lib pg-promise:

```
exports.getLawyerByUrlName = function (name_url, callback) {
    console.log(typeof name_url) //NOTICE: output string

    db.one({
            text: "SELECT * FROM " + lawyersTable + " WHERE name_url LIKE $1::varchar",
            values: name_url,
            name: "get-lawyer-by-name_url"
        })
        .then(function (lawyer) {
            callback(lawyer);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("getLawyerByUrlName() " + err)
        });
}
```

When it does not work it throws error:

```
getLawyerByUrlName() error: invalid input syntax for integer: "roberto-guzman-barquero"
```

This is a very weird bug I can't seem to catch why its happening. I'm checking before in console.log that I'm actually passing a string:

`console.log(typeof name_url) //NOTICE: output string`

My table field for name_url is:

```
CREATE TABLE lawyers(
...
  name_url VARCHAR check(translate(name_url, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-', '') = '') NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be unlikely that that particular query could ever throw that error so I'll suggest three possibilities. The first is that the code that's causing the error is actually someplace else and that:

```
.catch(function (err) {
            console.log("getLawyerByUrlName() " + err)
```

was cut and pasted into a different part of the code.

The 2nd possibility is that the "lawersTable" variable is getting populated with something unexpected.

The 3rd possibility is that my first two scenarios are wrong.  ;-)